# Android App If Else Statements

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I require a little bit of help with some java coding for my android guessing game app.

At the moment my if else statements cover whether a guess is too high, too low, or correct.  What I want it to do is tell the user if the answer they give is close to the answer or far away from it.  Say, within 50% or over 50% away.  I can do if else where it uses numbers but I'm stumped when I'm trying to work out how to get it to work out the percentage based on the random number that the program generates.  If it was a static number I'd be fine but I can't work it out this way.

Any help greatly appreciated.

```
package lab.mad.cct.c3375331task1;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;

public class Task1Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.task1_layout);

        final TextView textResponse = (TextView)           findViewById(R.id.txtResponse);
        final TextView guessText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAnswer);
        final EditText userGuess = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNumber);

        Button pressMe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGuess);



    // When the button is clicked, it shows the text assigned to the txtResponse TextView box
        pressMe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String randText = "";
                Random randGen = new Random();
                int ranNum = randGen.nextInt(5);
                int userNumber =   Integer.parseInt(userGuess.getText().toString());
                int attempts = 0;


                if (userNumber >19 ) {
                    guessText.setText("Please guess between 0 and 20");
                } else if (userNumber == ranNum) {
                    guessText.setText("You got it!");
                } else if (userNumber < ranNum) {
                    guessText.setText("Your answer is too low. Guess     again!");
                    guessText.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                } else if (userNumber > ranNum) {
                    guessText.setText("Your answer is too high.  Guess again!");
                }

                randText = Integer.toString(ranNum);
                textResponse.setText("");

                userGuess.setText("");

            }
        });

    } 



}
```

Comment: How do you define, "Within 50 percent?" If the number is 0 and they guess 1, is that within 50 percent?

Comment: Just as an aside, your user might get pretty frustrated with this app, as a new random number is created every time they press the button. Unless you intended for that to be the game :-)

Comment: That was going to be a question for another time.  I'd like it to stick with the number generated and only give the user 3 attempts.  But like I said, one step at a time for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the percentage difference between two numbers (the random number and the guessed number) like this:

```
public float percentDiff(int randomNumber, int guessedNumber) {

    int diff = Math.abs(randomNumber - guessedNumber);

    float diffPercentage = (float) diff / (float) randomNumber;

    System.out.println("" + diffPercentage);

    return diffPercentage; 

}
```

A value `>0.5` would be more than 50% off and vice versa.

Comment: This fails in the case of 0, which is said to be valid according to the error message. How do you actually define "within 50 percent?"

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider The concept of one number being 50 percent of another number' is pretty well defined. Except for 0, of course.

Comment: Sure it is. But that wasn't the requirement. The requirement was "within 50 percent" not "50 percent of". Maybe the asker meant the latter, but you can't assume that. It may seem like I'm mincing words, but in the context of the question and the sample program (`"Please guess between 0 and 20"`), it's a legitimate question.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider What he meant, in my understanding, was, to know if the difference between one number (random number) and another number (guessed number) is more than 50% of the first number. He expressed that as 'within 50%'.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate (on the fly) what the Users supplied number is percentage wise towards the randomly generated number then you can use a simple formula like:

```
int percentOf = ((userNumber * 100) / ranNum);
```